# How to count the length of element/class using javascript dynamically in realtime...?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Say there a '5' divs with the classname "item" and a new 'n' number of divs with same classname "item" is added dynamically in realtime... My result should show the total number of divs present at the time (i.e.., 5 + n ).

Note: no click or hover event is present.

```
<div class="wrapper">
      <div class="item"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/457882/pexels-photo-457882.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940g"></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/457882/pexels-photo-457882.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940g"></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/457882/pexels-photo-457882.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940g"></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/457882/pexels-photo-457882.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940g"></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/457882/pexels-photo-457882.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940g"></div>
</div>

<script>
var numItems = $('.item').length;
console.log(numItems);
</script>
```

This give result only on first load, but result I require must be dynamic in realtime.

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic in realtime?

Comment: Re-run that logic when new elements are added. To do that hook to the event which adds the elements, or use a MutationObserver. The former is by far the best way, if possible

Comment: This div will be populated to the user based on the area selected so the number of elements change

Comment: You can use as [RoryMcCrossan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55451157/how-to-count-the-length-of-element-class-using-javascript-dynamically-in-realtim#comment97616411_55451157) suggest or add `setInterval` which is *totally* **UNRECOMMENDED** unless you could `clearInterval` which I don't sure would be called with your note " no click or hover event is present."

Comment: MutationObserver worked.... !!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Mutation Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to observe the parent `wrapper` node for changes and then trigger a `callback` function whenever the DOM element is mutated.

See the below code for an example.

```js
const callback = () => {
  var numItems = $('.item').length;
  console.log(numItems);
};

const targetNode = $('.wrapper').get(0);
const config = {
  attributes: true,
  childList: true
};
// Setup the observer on the wrapper node
const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
observer.observe(targetNode, config);

// Display value initially
callback();

// Function to dynamically insert more nodes
setInterval(() => {
  const node = $("<div>").attr('class', 'item');
  $('.wrapper').eq(0).append(node);
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/457882/pexels-photo-457882.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940g"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/457882/pexels-photo-457882.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940g"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/457882/pexels-photo-457882.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940g"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/457882/pexels-photo-457882.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940g"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/457882/pexels-photo-457882.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940g"></div>
</div>
```

Please make sure to check the [Browser_compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver#Browser_compatibility) list for Mutation Observer.

Comment: It worked!!! I was able to take the count of the elements now dynamically and manipulate them... Cheers!!!